# How to get users having birthday today in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I need to send birthday wishes to users in my application.

I have a table User, with the column dateOfBirth. I need a query to retrieve users having date of birth matching today's date.

For example, if a user has dateOfBirth value 1983-08-07, I have to sent birthday wishes to the user.
I used below code but is is giving empty values, nothing gets from this query.

```
public function today(Request $request)
{
    $today = Carbon::now();
    $date = today();
    $user = user::whereDate('dateOfBirth', $today->day)->whereMonth('dateOfBirth', $today->isoFormat('DD'))->get();
    return view('today',compact('user'));
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: whereDate converts the value given into it to 'Y-m-d' format...whereDay would allow you to compare day. And looks like you have month in a separate column?.. maybe show your table ?

Comment: `dateOfBirth` format is `Y-m-d`?

Comment: Format column `dateOfBirth ` is timestamp?

Comment: dateOfBirth column has value like this "1983-08-07" and there is no separate column for the month.

Its not a timestamp.
 Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use  `whereMonth` and  `whereDay`

```
$today=now();

$user=User::whereMonth('dateOfBirth',$today->month)
            ->whereDay('dateOfBirth',$today->day)
            ->get();
```

Comment: This is not working either, it still shows empty., https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NJJaabOYBvuaXw0tur9r7_f-wauf1w6h/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @J.Lee whats is type of dateOfBirth  in database ? is it date  or varchar ?

Comment: Thank you!!, it is working now, it's my bad that I do not have users who matched with today's date.

Answer (score 0):

When you use whereDate function, make sure the date you pass in matches the sql format.You can use function date('d-m-Y H:i:s'); to format current time

Answer (score 0):

if I'm not mistaken type column `dateOfBirth` is string.
So you can not use `whereMonth` and  `whereDay`.

Solve :

```
user::where('dateOfBirth', 'LIKE', '%' . Carbon::now()->format('-m-d'))->get();
```

Or
Change type `dateOfBirth` to `timestamp`.